# Convert only one item with dictionary comprehension

Tags: python, dictionary

Cheers,

I'm currently working on a piece of code and and I'm trying to find the best, more pythonic and CPU low cost solution for my problem.

I actually have a array of "index   value" which I read through a file, an example is:

```
>>> list = ['index_1    200', 'index_2    500', 'index_3    50']
>>>
>>> list
['index_1    200', 'index_2    500', 'index_3    50']
```

I'm trying to create a dictionary comprehension where I will maintain the index name as a `string` but convert the value to an `int`. The way I've found to accomplish this goal was:

```
>>> dict((line.split()[0], int(line.split()[1])) for line in list)
{'index_2': 500, 'index_3': 50, 'index_1': 200}
```

But the `(line.split()[0], int(line.split()[1])` part looks like something that could be done in a better way, since that my list example is really just an example, I may find huge lines of indexes later on.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can avoid splitting each string twice, and you can make use of a dictionary comprehension like this:

```
>>> mylist = ['index_1    200', 'index_2    500', 'index_3    50']
>>> mydict = {k:int(v) for (k,v) in (line.split() for line in mylist)}
>>> mydict
{'index_2': 500, 'index_3': 50, 'index_1': 200}
```

*Edit*

In Python 2.6 you can do pretty much the same thing but without the dict comprehension syntax:

```
 >>> mydict = dict((k,int(v)) for (k,v) in (line.split() for line in mylist))
```

Comment: works like a charm on Python 2.7+. Any chance to have a similar on Python 2.6?

Comment: that's just beautiful.